# JBoss Drools - BPMN IntelliJ Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, drools, bpmn

I am looking for a plugin to use in IntelliJ to edit visually a .bpmn file. I installed the JBoss jBPM plugin, but it doesn't associate or open up a *.bpmn2 file. Can someone suggest if this supported in IntelliJ or another plugin is available to visually edit a .bpmn2 file?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, most BPMN 2.0 engines I've seen use slightly different dialects. It means that the file structure is the same. But the details, like executed Java class reference, are provided in a slightly different way, for example by using custom XML namespace that is relevant to the concrete BPMN engine.

I've created a plugin for **Flowable BPMN** and IntelliJ with navigation-to-code-support:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14318-flowable-bpmn-visualizer

And sources are here:
https://github.com/valb3r/flowable-bpmn-intellij-plugin

What I suggest is community participation in expanding this plugin or forking it to support i.e. **JBPMN** BPMN 2.0 dialect, as all we need to change is XML Parser, and all other parts of the plugin can remain as is

Answer (score 2):

JBoss JBPM plugin is an old plugin that covers Jboss proprietary jPDL notation but doesn't cover BPMN. There is also ActiBPM plugin ((https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7429?pr=), but it seems to be dead. Unfortunately there is no better tool for IntelliJ, so you probably remain stuck with your current tools (I'm stuck with Eclipse + Camunda plugin).

Answer (score 1):

You may try **PolyBPMN visualiser** Intellij IDEA plugin
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21361-polybpmn-visualizer

It supports files with extension *.bpmn, *.bpmn.xml *.bpmn20.

See also polybpmn.com